# Can't pass data via segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I make app with news feed which has to open on other ViewController. But can't pass data via segue.

**Viewcontroller with newsfeed**

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var titlenews = ""

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "newsfeedCell", for: indexPath) as! NewsFeedCell
    cell.newsfeed_title.text = self.news?[indexPath.item].headline
    cell.newsfeed_topic.text = self.news?[indexPath.item].topic
    cell.newsfeed_time.text = timetime(from: (self.news?[indexPath.item].time)!)
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("tableview")
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "newsBody") as? NewsBody
    vc?.labeltext = (self.news?[indexPath.item].headline)!
    print((self.news?[indexPath.item].headline)!)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
} 

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.news!.count
} //number of rows

@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
var news: [Newsfeed]? = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getJSON()
}

func getJSON(){
 ///Here all do right 
}
}
```

**Viewcontroller which has to receive data from news feed**

```
  class NewsBody: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!

    var labeltext = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(labeltext)
        testLabel.text = labeltext
    }
}
```

`print(labeltext)` shows that `NewsBody` receive empty value or nothing.

But `print((self.news?[indexPath.item].headline)!)` inside of `SecondViewController` shows that I try to push proper value.

What I do incorrect between this actions? What wrong with segue and pass of data?

Comment: have you added sague in storyboard from viewController to SecondViewController?

Comment: There is not segue use in your current code. You are doing yourself in the old way the pushViewController, but not doing a segue.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "newsBody")` triggers view load under the hood. It should not (in theory) but it might do just that in your case.

This means that `viewDidLoad()` will be called before the `vc?.labeltext = (self.news?[indexPath.item].headline)!` is executed.

I'd recommend you to do the following.

```
class NewsBody: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!

  var labeltext: String? {
    didSet { updateUI() }
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    updateUI()
  }

  private func updateUI() {
    testLabel.text = labeltext
  }
}
```

This way if you set the `labeltext` property after the view is loaded, it will still trigger the UI update. And if you set the `labeltext` property before the view is loaded, as soon as `viewDidLoad()` is called.

BTW, you are not using segues here. But even if you do, you can easily use the same method as I proposed, because it allows you to stop thinking about whether property updates will update the UI.

---

Also please note that I made the property optional. It will allow you to avoid force casts and just do

```
vc?.labeltext = self.news?[indexPath.item].headline
```

`UILabel.text` is also an optional `String` property, so they will play well together.